# after installing php5.2.6 php info won't show

Tags: php

For some reason I need to downgrade the php5.4 to 5.2.6 I've already manually installed the php5.2.6 after compiling it was success.. no errors where encountered. but funny thing is that when i php -v it is telling me that php is not installed.

Sever setup
default apache httpd is installed.
removed php5.4 and downgraded it to php5.2.6

I've already tried everything I found over the net but still can't figure out what I have missed along the way.. I'm just a newbie here and your expert advice will really help.. Thanks in advance..

Cheers

Comment: restart your service/server.

Comment: i've already done that.. still the same..

Comment: i've also notice that i can't sinf /bin/php

Comment: Ok, Another way is to check by create info.php with `<?php
phpinfo();

?>` and execute it.

Comment: i've already done that as well.. http://localhost/info.php and it won't show the  php info just a plain text <?php
phpinfo();
?>

Comment: Doesn't php need to be installed as apache mod?

Comment: Another question: **Why** would you downgrade PHP? There is absolutely no reason to.

Comment: the reason why I need to downgrade is because our programmer is using an old code in which it only run under php5.2.6.. I've already followed all configuration for both apache and php over the net.. but right now I can't figure out how to make it work..

Comment: **Stop using that version of PHP.** It's obsolete, it's unsupported, and it's affected by numerous *major* security vulnerabilities. If the software you're using doesn't work on newer versions of PHP, it's also obsolete and you need to replace it.

Comment: indeed.. but that I was told by the programmer that he needs to run his code on php5.2.6 and I've already explained the security vulnerabilities but he insisted on it and I have no other choice but to follow and do my job.. he even tag our president to instruct me to follow what he wants :(

Comment: You may want to explain to the president that the company is at risk if you do what the alleged programmer wants you to do. As others have said, you are taking a risk by downgrading to that version of PHP. PHP 5.2 went out of service over 5 years ago (6 Jan 2011).

Comment: let him update the code to mysqli or PDO, because downgrading the php version will only cause security holes as deep as the grand canyon(there is a reason it went obsolete and is unsupported). Or as @duskwuff stated replace it.

Comment: @Dave And 5.2.6 is even older. May 2008.

Comment: Can you share your companies name? If I have an account I need to delete it.